# “Best Practice” way to get value from child record saved to parent record

Tags: apex, trigger, data, automation, after-trigger

I get similar business requirements that ask:

> Get the latest child record where field X is not null, and copy field X's value to its parent's field Y

The solution must work with bother master-detail and lookup relationships. An example could be, for all the Contacts of an Account, copy the latest created Contact's First and Last Name to the "Newest Contact's Name" field on the Account.

My go to solution for this request would be to call apex code in an `after insert` context of the object's trigger to do the query and update in a bulkified way. It's worked out pretty well. Is there a better? I apologize in advanced if this question is too broad.

Comment: Better is a value judgment. How are you measuring your "better"?

Comment: Better as in Best Practice, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

I've always done this with [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries), rather than trying to write all my own triggers. It's faster, easier, and less error-prone. I'd drop down to handwritten triggers only in situations where extreme data volume or performance considerations are present.

In DLRS, you do this by setting up a rollup summary with `Field to Aggregate` set to the field name you want (`Name`, in your example), and `Field to Order By` set to `CreatedDate`. Then just pick `First` or `Last` as your `Aggregate Operation`.

Once you've deployed DLRS's generated triggers, this results in the value of `Field to Aggregate` from the most-recent child record being populated on the parent, with no handwritten code required.

Comment: I’ll try it out in a sandbox and see if it makes sense. Thank you!